# why does resharper tell me this js code is unreachable?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Within a js implementation of a module design pattern I've defined several functions.  I wanted to break out some long html string variables into an object separate from the function using it so I defined the following object:

```
var resources = 
{
    htmlVar1:'...',
    htmlVar2:'...'
}
```

However, Resharper is telling me 'Code is unreachable'.  Is this error correct?  If so then how would you normally implement something like this within the context of a js module design pattern?

Comment: Code is usually unreachable if it comes after a `return` statement.

Comment: We need to see the whole function that this appears in.

Comment: Please also tell us exactly which line is unreachable, in addition to the full function of text being supplied. Is it the line you showed or another one?

Comment: Thanks xufox, I moved the module return statement from the top to the bottom of the js module and the Resharper error went away.  I guess this specific error is specific to vars rather than functions defined within the context of a module.  Was it valid for Resharper to report this as an error?  I didn't test the error explicitly.  I've used Resharper for years with C# but I've only been using Resharper with js for a few weeks so I don't have a feel for how reliable Resharper is with js yet.

Comment: "I moved the module return statement from the top to the bottom of the js module" --- o_O

Comment: @user6604655 As long as your `return` was in the same scope as your `var` and was not conditional then it was valid. `return` exits from the current block of code, and your `var` would never be declared. Hard to tell without the rest of your code though.

Comment: @miked to be precise: the variable would be declared but not initialised.